# Windows 7 script to change part of a file name

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, script, batch-rename

I have a collection of files whose names are in the form `car-#######-NNNNNNN.xxx`,
where *`#######`* is a series of numbers that need to be kept as part of the file name,
and *`xxx`* is an extension denoting the file format, such as "jpg", "bmp", or "png",
which also needs to be kept.
I need to remove the `car-` and the `-NNNNNNN`
(duplication of the `-#######`) from the file name,
leaving only `#######.xxx`.

Is this possible and how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Copy this text into a text editor (Notepad) and save the file as `rename.bat` into the folder where the files are located and run it.

Change `xxx` in the line `IF %ext% EQU xxx ren %1 "%fnum%.%ext%"` to whatever extension your files are saved in.

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "tokens=*" %%i ^
in ('forfiles /d +0 /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE echo @file"') ^
do call :subroutine %%i
pause

:subroutine
set fname=%1
set ext=%fname:~-4,3%
set fnum=%fname:~5,7%
REM echo %fnum%
REM echo %ext%
IF %ext% EQU xxx ren %1 "%fnum%.%ext%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Vinayak’s answer looks OK if your *`#######`* is always exactly seven characters. 
If the number of characters can vary, and you want to work by delimiter rather than count, try

```
for /f "delims=-. tokens=1-4" %a in ('dir /b/a-d car-*-*.*') ^
                                    do @echo ren %a-%b-%c.%d %b.%d
```

Run this, and, if it shows you the correct rename commands,
delete the `echo` and run it again. 
I split this into two lines so it would fit on the screen;
if you prefer, you can make it all one line (delete the `^`). 
If you put this into a script (batch file), change all occurrences of `%` to `%%`.

Warning: if your *`NNNNNNN`* is not always a duplicate of your *`#######`*,
e.g., you have files named `car-1234567-1234567.jpg` and `car-1234567-9999999.jpg`,
this will rename the first one it finds and give error messages for the others.

Answer (score -1):

Windows file manager does not provide complex multiple file renaming functionality with use of patterns or regular expressions (unlike normal file managers do).

I would recommend doing the job under linux if you have a linux distro available. Just use [Nautilus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files) and you will be able to mass-rename and use pattern-based search/replace functionality.

Alternatively, if you don't have access to linux distro, try to install [Total Commander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Commander). This file manager has good mass-renaming functionality. You can alos read a nice guide on [this page](http://beerpla.net/2008/03/12/mass-renaming-directories-and-files-using-total-commander/).

Comment: I think he's looking for a batch script to achieve this as the question says "Windows 7 script..."

Comment: @Vinayak, correct, however I thought that using a file manager like TC could be an acceptable solution to the actual problem. Its up to OP to decide what is best for him.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I hadn't read the part about Total Commander. I'd also like to add that [ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=renamer) is a pretty good tool to consider, if all the OP wants is to rename stuff.